# SQL Server Changing comments in stored procedures

Tags: sql-server-2012

When opening an already existing stored procedure or function, it shows at the top

```
/****** Object:  StoredProcedure [dbo].[spMySP]    Script Date: 04.12.2015 09:01:18 ******/
```

Is there an option that also shows the creation date of the stored procedure, not only the current datetime, when I am trying to alter something?

I am using SQL Server 2012.

Thanks
Michael

Answer (score 0):

No, you can't change what is in that comment as far as I'm aware, I know you can turn it on or off, but that's about it.

You can however find the created/last modified date for procedures in the database if you want to include it in your header by running this:

```
SELECT name,
       create_date,
       modify_date
FROM sys.procedures
```